# Keep elements order inside OrderedDict

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and I'm trying dicts, the problem as you know is that the order inside dicts isn't kept so I'm using OrderedDicts to perform this issue but I have no success.

This is the kind of dict that I'm trying:

```
numbersDictionary = OrderedDict({ 
      "0":{ (0,1),(1,0),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) },
      "1":{ (1,2),(2,3) },
      "2":{ (0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,1),(2,2) },
      "3":{ (0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3) },
      "4":{ (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3) },
      "5":{ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3) },
      "6":{ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) },
      "7":{ (0,1),(1,2),(2,3) },
      "8":{ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) },
      "9":{ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3) }
    });
```

So when I do something like this:

```
print(numbersDictionary.get("5"))
```

The output:

```
{(0, 1), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
```

How can I build my dict of that data in order to get the correct order elements?

Comment: Why are you using a dict here at all? Why not a list? In any case, your problem is that your values are `set` objects, which are unordered. Again, why not `list` objects?

Comment: Actually yes I'm playing around with Python, I'm new so thats the reason.. anyway it's fixed now XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using the wrong data types in the first place. Your keys are literally string representations of indexes; that’s what lists are for! Use a list to store this data.

As for the set’s, you are most likely aiming to use lists here as well as lists retain order while sets do not, they are “unordered collections of unique elements”.

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
numbers = [
      [(0,1),(1,0),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
      [(1,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,1),(2,2)],
      [(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3)],
      [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)],
      [(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3)]
]
```

With your data stored this way you can access the sub-lists using their index as an int.

```
>>> numbers[5]
>>> [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: If this answered your question then please change this to your accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the `OrderedDict` itself, but the use of sets as the dictionary values. **Sets are unordered.** Use lists instead.

This is a `set`:

```
{ (1,2),(2,3) }
```

This is a `list`:

```
[ (1,2),(2,3) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`OrderedDict` keeps the order of keys, not values. Here, you want your values ordered so `list` is the right data structure.

```
>>> numbersDictionary = { 
  "0": [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) ],
  "1": [ (1,2),(2,3) ],
  "2": [ (0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,1),(2,2) ],
  "3": [ (0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3) ],
  "4": [ (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3) ],
  "5": [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3) ],
  "6": [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) ],
  "7": [ (0,1),(1,2),(2,3) ],
  "8": [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3) ],
  "9": [ (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3) ]
}

>>> numbersDictionary["5"]
>>> [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```